# Displaying a chartjs chart within a bulma full height hero

Tags: css, chart.js, bulma

I am trying to display a chartjs chart within a bulma fullscreen hero section. The desired effect is that the section will take up the available browser space. I would also need for the chart to remain responsive.

It would also be good to be able to add a some text above the chart, a title and subtitle.

The code below works but chartjs become non-responsive.

```html
<!-- Section: First Chart -->
<section class="hero is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I try and add a title we overflow the full height:

```html
<!-- Section: First Chart -->
<section class="hero is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title has-text-grey-dark">
        My title
      </h1>
      <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try to move `<canvas id="chart"></canvas>` to `<div class="hero-body">` or try to set `<div class="container">` **height 100%**.

Comment: No neither works.

Comment: Hi, have you tried my variant in the answer below? If yes did it help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to do the same thing

```html
    <!-- Section: First Chart -->
    <section class="hero is-fullheight">
      <div>
      <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I think you do not need the container and add the title via the chart.js

Let me know if it helped.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="hero is-primary is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        title: {
         display: true,
          text: 'Custom Chart Title',
          fontSize: 24,
          fontColor: '#fff'
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: No this does not work either, on all screen sizes seems to work on a small laptop but not large screen. Also I need to add a title, the fix cannot be to remove needed content....